# Error importing excel: Could not initialize class org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.ZipPackagePropertiesMarshaller

Tags: java, apache-poi, websphere

I am having a problem with using apache poi for importing excel file. My application run successfully in UAT environment but in production I got the error:

```
[4/17/20 18:12:36:597 ICT] 00003b2f ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service Uncaught service() exception thrown by servlet FileImportData: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.ZipPackagePropertiesMarshaller
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.init(OPCPackage.java:161)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.<init>(OPCPackage.java:141)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:97)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:324)
    at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:295)
    at com.bidv.qlcsdlsibs.v2.servlet.FileImportData.doPost(FileImportData.java:87)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3837)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:558)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:608)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:985)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1074)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1864)
```

I think the problem happened at line:

```
Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
```

I am using lib: **poi-3.17.jar, poi-ooxml-3.17.jar, ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar**
I deploy application on IBM Websphere Portal 8.5.5.2 (both UAT and production), using java 1.7. Please see my lib folder

[image]

Comment: Can you search your logs for additional exceptions? The error message indicates that something went wrong in the static initialization of ZipPackagePropertiesMarshaller - the method name for the static initializer is `<clinit>`, and I sometimes find it useful to just search the logs for "clinit" and see if it shows up in any stacks.

Comment: Thanks @Jarid: I don't know what is <clinit>, I search google but not found much information about that

Comment: It's the name of the method that represents the static initialization of a class (generally stuff that's in a static{} block). Search for that string in your log files to see if it's in any exception stacks - if it is, that's probably the root error causing your problem.

Comment: Yes. I can't find this name in my log. I am using ex.getMessage() method, maybe need to write full message of the exception

Comment: I'd start with figuring out what's different between UAT & production environments.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem by chosing another Java runtime environment (chose JRE of IBM Websphere instead of using another JRE) for building the project. Thank you !